# Serialize multiple streams into a single one

Tags: c#, performance, serialization

I've got a scenario where I need to backup thousands of rather small (1-3KB) files (in Azure blob storage, but that's not the point) which I have as a list of these models (source code of which I don't own - it's Azure SDK):

```
class Model {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Stream Data {get;}
  //bunch of other things I'd like to ignore
}
```

My best attempt (from performance point of view) is now merging them all in a single file using JsonTextWriter from Json.NET, but obviously I don't need text format here and it introduces a lot of overheads. I'm wondering if there is any (binary?) serializer available which won't require me to decorate existing model with some specific attributes and will also have a nice API including something like

```
var writer = new MagicWriterThatImLookingFor();
foreach(var model in models){
  writer.WriteString(model.Name);
  writer.WriteByteArray(model.Data.ToArray());
}
```

with corresponding deserialize?

Comment: `BinaryWriter` seems to match your requirements

Comment: @Evk I don't have a way to read the byte array back from it with BinaryReader though - it needs the size of bytes to read

Comment: Well, write its length first (`writer.Write(myBytes.Length); writer.Write(myBytes)`), then read with `int length = reader.ReadInt32(); byte[] myBytes = reader.ReadBytes(length)`

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if there's something else with maybe better performance (taking advantage of parallelism?), because existing benchmarks that I found do not match this exact scenario that I have

Comment: It will be dominated by IO (you are going to write that to azure, so network IO), so I doubt parallelizm will help much. Unless you want to store in multiple different azure blobs - but then you can parallelize yourself.

Comment: @Evk yeah seems like BinaryWriter is the most reasonable choice

Comment: I think so, and I believe it's fast. No reflection, no attributes. You just tell it what exactly to write, it's pretty low-level.

Comment: Have you thought about using the [`System.IO.Packaging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging(v=vs.110).aspx) API?  It allows for multiple streams (not necessarily XML or text) to be combined into a single archive along with a mechanism to establish relationships between them.